# How to test with Rspec and ActionController::Live while writing to stream in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently experimenting with ActionController::Live and I can't figure out how to test    this properly.

In my controller I have this written

```
       response.stream.write("event: #{event}\n")
       response.stream.write("data: #{post.to_json}\n\n")
```

But when I inspect the object in my rspec test I see this

```
       (rdb:1) response.stream.instance_variable_get(:@buf)
       ["event: event\n"]
```

When I write the "data" to the stream, I can't figure out whyit doesn't show up in the array. When I remove the first response.stream.write line the buf returns an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Calling to_json in the stream.write doesn't add the stream into the buf instance variable. so I stubbed out to_json and forced a return value, now I can make sure that the stream is writing properly